# When NSString changes, `do something` only being called once even after change

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstring

Here is my code:

.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>{
    NSString *lastValue;
}
```

.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    lastValue = nil; 
}

- (void) fullDMXReceived:(NSString*)finalData {

    if (finalData != lastValue) {
        lastValue = finalData;

        // doing something
     }
}
```

For some reason, 'doing something' is only called once, and it stops.

Some background info: 'fullDMXReceived' is called every 100 miliseconds or so with new information. Sometimes (many times actually) the data is the same, and thus, I do not want 'doing something' to run. If it's different, I DO want 'doing something' to happen.

I'm not sure why it's only running 'doing something' once even when the finalData changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: where is `doing something` in your code?

Comment: It's right there. It's just parsing final data and controlling a slider accordingly.

Comment: try nslog-ing above if, is it getting called every 100ms?

Comment: What code is calling `fullDMXReceived:`?

Comment: It's being called by another method like this:             [self fullDMXReceived:buffer];

Comment: Sorry, I meant what code is making it get called every 100ms?

Comment: When ever new data is received over the serial port, - (void) receivedData:(NSString *)data runs with the [self fullDMXReceived:buffer] in it.

Comment: Is buffer in `fullDMXReceived:` a `NSMutableString` instance that is reused?

Comment: Yep! After I send [self fullDMXReceived:buffer] , I erase the buffer. [buffer setString @""];

Comment: I guess that is your problem then, `lastValue = finalData` will only assign the same reference and not actually copy the string.

Comment: Wait i´ll make a more proper answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `buffer` in `fullDMXReceived:` is a `NSMutableString` instance that is reused you will need to copy the actual string instead of just assign the instance, try something like this:

```
- (void) fullDMXReceived:(NSString*)finalData {
    if (finalData != nil &&
        ![finalData isEqualToString:lastValue]) {
        [lastValue release]; // only needed if you don't use ARC
        lastValue = [finalData copy];
        // doing something
     }
}
```

Comment: CLOSER! Now it's 'doing something' when it changes. But for some reason, it's being called every like 10-20 seconds randomly when the string hasn't changed.

Comment: Could it be that buffer is `nil` in those cases? the `if`-condition will probably be true then as `[nil isEqualToString:lastValue]` will be `nil` and then `!nil` will be true.

Comment: Should I add an if statement when it is nil, don't do anything?

Comment: Hmmm yeah but i guess it depends how you would like it to work, would you like to "do something" the first time `finalData` is `nil` when it previously was a string?

Comment: Well, when it's nil anytime, don't do anything I suppose

Comment: Something like that? now `nil` calls will be ignored.

Comment: I did this:     if ((![finalData isEqualToString:lastValue]) & (![finalData isEqualToString:nil])) { and it's still running 'doing something' randomly.

Comment: Getting this: Server[1601:303] last <DMX>0,0,0,0,0</DMX>
Server[1601:303] current <DMX>0,0,0,0,0</DMX>

Comment: And I put the log, where 'doing something' is. That's weird!

Comment: You can't really use `nil` with `isEqualToString:`, it might not crash but the result is a bit undefined. You should check for nil with just `finalData != nil` for example. Note also that `&` is bitwise and, you probably want `&&` which is logical and.

Comment: `![finalData isEqualToString:nil]` is incorrect. It should be `finalData != nil`.

Comment: Yep, I used your code instead - same thing. Thanks for the tip though! Learned something new!

Comment: So you get a log message where current and last are the same inside doing something? do you log after `lastValue = [finalData copy]`?

Comment: Yeah! randomly around every 10 seconds. BUT, it does run when I change the value - so that works.

Comment: And yep, I log after 'lastValue = [finalData copy]'

Comment: If you log after doing `lastValue = [finalData copy]` then they _should_ be the same :) so move the log before it.

Comment: Weird, SAME AGAIN. Server[1653:303] <DMX>0,0,0,0,0</DMX>
Server[1653:303] <DMX>0,0,0,0,0</DMX>

Comment: Can you paste your full code somewhere? like in some pastbin etc

Comment: The WHOLE thing? I could email it to you, if you don't mind giving out your email.

Comment: I really do appreciate it. I've been staring at the screen blindly the last couple days trying to figure it out. :)

Comment: Maybe just the current .m file is enough

Comment: I see and i understand that Objective-C can be very confusing language because of the mashup of C and a very dynamic object system :)

Comment: Just posted! - Yeah :-) well, I'm still getting into it. I love coding so much, just every once and a while, I hit a brick wall and require some assistance :-)

Comment: FYI, receivedData is being called by another class, like this,      AppDelegate *theAppDelegate =[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [theAppDelegate receivedData:string];

Comment: Are you really the strings are the same? not any trailing whitespaces, line endings etc? try to add "" around %@ in the log to make sure. I did some tests and the code seems to work for me http://pastebin.com/iDGLmkMA

Comment: SPACING PROBLEM! : last value = '
<DMX>116,110,74,0,0</DMX>
', current value = '<DMX>116,110,74,0,0</DMX>
'

Comment: Got it:
NSString *trimmedData = [finalData stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                  [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

Comment: :) yeah you can use `[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]` to trim leading and ending space and new lines characters.

Comment: No problem, it's nice to help :) good luck with your application, DMX... isn't that light control stuff?

Comment: Thanks! And yep, I have an arduino that receives DMX and sends the data through the serial port to the mac app <DMX>255,255,255,255,255</DMX>

Answer (score 0):

I wonder there is no setter/getter / @property for your lastValue..try implementing it and then check if problem exists.

EDIT:

Change your code as :

```
.h

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property(strong)  NSString *lastValue;
@end

.m

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
   _lastValue = nil; 
}

- (void) fullDMXReceived:(NSString*)finalData {

    if (![finalData isEqualToString:_lastValue]) {
        _lastValue = finalData;

        // doing something
     }
}
```

Comment: Let me try! Thanks, Anoop.

Comment: Server[1401:303] finalData = <DMX>0,0,0,0,0</DMX>, lastValue = <DMX>0,0,0,0,0</DMX>
Server[1401:303] finalData = <DMX>59,0,0,0,0</DMX>, lastValue = <DMX>59,0,0,0,0</DMX>

Comment: For some reason still not reading the last value correctly. They both change at the same time